# SQL / SQlite nested select in having clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was playing a bit with sqlite and encountered the following problem: it looks like it is not possible to nest a subquery in a having clause

When I try to call a query with:

```
... having count(select * from produkt) > 1
```

I get the error:

> OperationalError: near "select": syntax error

While executing

```
 ... having count(1) > 1
```

everything is fine

Would you have any workarounds for that?

edit2:

I want to write this:

```
select distinct standort.name, standort.ort
from produktion
    join standort on id_standort = standort.id
    join produkt on id_produkt = produkt.id
where produkt.gewicht < 1

EXCEPT

select distinct standort.name, standort.ort
from produktion
    join standort on id_standort = standort.id
    join produkt on id_produkt = produkt.id
where produkt.kategorie = "Spiel"
```

In a more elegant way, using "having"

Cheers and thanks a lot!

Wojtek

Comment: Include the query in the question, as text.  You have enough reputation to know that questions should be complete and not refer to off-site pages (except for additional helpful information).

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok done, i just thought it would be easier with an interactive jupyter notebook

Comment: I guess I don't understand your intention from your select statement. What I read is that you are selecting from produktion, grouping by standort, but don't want to get back any relults if produkt table is empty. But what I think you might be say is "select from produktion, group by standort but exclude any group where there is no matching produkt" Yes?

Comment: @bit2know I simply want to get all "Standort" satisfying 2 conditions:

1. produkt.kategorie is not "Spiel"
2. There is at least one produkt.gewicht > 1

Answer (score 2):

I think this fits your intention better than your current select

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Standort
     JOIN produktion ...
     JOIN produkt ...
WHERE product.kategorie != "Spiel" AND produkt.gewicht > 1
```

Comment: This is not the same thing.  This assumes the values are in the same row.  So, I understand the answer, but not the upvotes.

Comment: What do you mean "values are in the same row"? it's a inner join

Comment: Each `standort.name, standort.ort` combination could appear on multiple rows.  The `kategorie` condition and `gewicht` conditions could be on different rows (produced by the `inner join`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure in what context you would do this, but this is syntactically correct:

```
having (select count(*) from produkt) > 1
```

EDIT:

For your actual question, this query is simpler:

```
select s.name, s.ort
from produktion pn join
     standort s
     on pn.id_standort = s.id join
     produkt p
     on pn.id_produkt = p.id
group by s.name, s.ort
having sum(case when p.gewicht < 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when p.kategorie = 'Spiel' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This returns all `s.name`/`s.ort` combinations that have a "gewicht" less than 1 and no "kategorie" called `'Spiel'`.